# How to import certificate file in firefox for deployment?

Tags: deployment, firefox

I tried the settings in this [link](https://support.umbrella.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000669728-Configuring-Firefox-to-use-the-Windows-Certificate-Store) to use the system default certificate store in firefox but not working.

The firefox is not showing certificates from system store.

[image: certificate]

It is using its own section, which is in the profile folder of firefox in appdata of user, with name cert9.db.

[image: settings]

Even I tried setting custom location to it but not using that.

```
    "%~dp0certmgr.exe" -add -all -c "%~dp0BCLP_Decrypt.crt" -s -r localMachine Root
    copy /Y "%~dp0local-settings.js" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\local-settings.js"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox" /v DisableAppUpdate /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox" /v SharedCertDB /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\cert9.db\"" /f
    copy /Y "%~dp0umbrella.cfg" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\umbrella.cfg"
```

umbrella.cfg:

```
//
lockPref("security.enterprise_roots.enabled", true);
defaultPref("security.enterprise_roots.enabled", true);
defaultPref("security.enterprise_roots.storeDirectory", "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\cert9.db");
lockPref("security.enterprise_roots.storeDirectory", "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\cert9.db");
```

local-settings.js:

```
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
pref("general.config.filename", "umbrella.cfg");
```

Even tried this setting by saving to file: "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\all-users.js"

```
pref("security.enterprise_roots.enabled", true);
```

Comment: have you confirmed that the settings from `umbrella.cfg` are present in firefox?

Comment: Yes these settings are applied in firefox, as I showed in the screenshot before. But certificate is not showing